# How to structure input for downstream model in Smart Reply for Customer-Agent Utterances

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, chatbot

I am trying to develop architecture for Customer-Agent smart reply system for chat bot. I am taking help of Googles paper published in 2016:

https://research.google/pubs/pub45189/

This talks about smart reply in Gmail use case scenario. And our objective is to do it for chat-bot case scenario where Agent and Customer Utterances happen.

The problem that I am facing is:

How should I structure my Input/ Feed my input (i.e, Agent-Customer Utterances) for the downstream model to get the top 3 or 5 responses? How model should understand that which is Agent and which is Customer Utterances?

Input looks like:

```
Agent: Welcome to XYZ. How can I assist you?
Customer: I am facing issue withe internet?
Agent: May I know your registered mobile number?
Customer: My mobile number is XXXX. My email ID is XXX@yyy.com. 
Customer: Please resolve my issue asap.
```

Customer or Agent can have more than one utterances and one Utterances can have more than 1 sentences in that session.

How the input should be fed to model so that we get desired smart reply?

Like in the above example it can be:

```
Agent Smart Reply 1: We are working on it Mr.XXX
Agent Smart Reply 2: Your issue is resolved. Thanks for contacting XYZ
Agent Smart Reply 3: Your issue will take some time to get resolved. Please wait for 24 -48 hrs.
```

How we can fed the Customer-Agent Utterances to model? Any paper with reproducible code or any new suggestion will be helpful.